# Is there a way to config Gradle default log output?

Tags: gradle

I found the default Gradle log output too verbose. Is there a way to not have it print all the "UP-TO-DATE" tasks, and just show the warnings and errors?

Answer (score 1):

For sure, you just have to use the `-q` parameter